# How to I remove the first character of a string in Puppet 3.4?

Tags: puppet

I need to remove the first character of a string in Puppet 3.4.3.

I tried to find a way to do it in pure Puppet, but Puppet 3 doesn't seem to have very complete string manipulation capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet does not have a built-in substring function, but it has `regsubst()` for performing regex-based substitutions.  This can do what you ask, and much more.  For example:

```
$truncated = regsubst($original, '^.(.*)$', '\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it in pure Puppet 3.4.  However, it can be done easily with an inline template.

```
$truncated = inline_template('<%= @original[1..-1] %>')
```